# equivalent hensel lemma in the case of the rings Z/p*l Z

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

does exist an equivalent of the hensel lemma which permits the passage from the  unity roots of finite field s into roots of unity in characteristic 0 ; in the case of the rings Z/p*l Z

Comment: The field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ already has characteristic zero.

Comment: I’m sorry, I can’t understand your question. In particular, I‘m not sure what “$p*l$” is. Is that the product of two primes? If so, your quotient ring is not of characteristic zero.

Comment: No I mean p power l.

Comment: Yes the quotient ring  Z/(p*l)Z is of characteristic p*l, i.e its characteristic different from zero, like the case of the case of the finite fields; that is why , I would like to know i f there is an analogue of lemma hensel in those rings, similar to the lemma hensel of the finite fields.

Comment: Well. There is the obvious version that if a polynomial $f(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$ factors as $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ in $\Bbb{Z}/{p^\ell}\Bbb{Z}[x]$ with monic $f,g,h$ such that $\gcd(g(x),h(x))=1\in\Bbb{Z}/{p}\Bbb{Z}[x]$, then the factorization can be lifted to one in the $p$-adics. This follows from the usual Hensel Lemma, because we can reduce all of $f,g,h$ modulo $p$ :-)

Comment: Another possibility is to have roots of unity of order $p^f-1$ in some extension ring of $\Bbb{Z}/p^\ell\Bbb{Z}$. They are very transparent in the construction of the ring of Witt vectors of the field $\Bbb{F}_{p^f}$. Just truncate the Witt vectors to $\ell$ components.